# python getcolors with image mask

Tags: python, image-processing

I want to get the colors of an image without considering the colors of the background.
I have a binary image mask that represents the background pixels.
Is there a method like PIL's getcolors that can take this mask and return only non bg colors?
I'm trying to find an efficient implementation, I know I can itterate through all the pixels and count them...

Thx,
Li

Comment: I don't know much about PIL, but if you already have a mask of the background, this is really easy with Boolean indexing in numpy

Comment: You could add an alpha channel initialized with zeros, set the alpha of the masked pixels to 1 and then throw away any results from getcolors that have an alpha of 1.